# PCINT0 interrupt on attiny

Tags: avr, assembly

I'm started working with AVRs few days ago. Started with assembler and simulating in Proteus.

My current goal is to enable Pin Change interrupt on PCINT0, which is PB0 on my *attiny13*. Right now I'm following problem. I've enabled `external interrupt request`, but not able to make chip to trigger interrupt on PCINT0 pin.

[image: This is my current layout]

Code is

```
.device attiny13
;       --- Code segment ---
.CSEG
.ORG $0     ; interrupt vector table
    rjmp Reset      ; reset handler
    nop     ; IRQ0
    rjmp PCINT      ; PCINT0 (pin INT0 to INT5) PCMSK, MCUCR
    nop     ; Timer 0 overflow
    nop     ; EEPROM ready
    nop     ; Analog comparator
    nop     ; Timer 0 compare A
    nop     ; Timer 0 compare B
    nop     ; watchdog
    nop     ; ADC conversion    

.ORG 0x10       ; staring after interrupt vector table

    rjmp  Start
PCINT:
    reti
Reset:
    ldi r16, low(RAMEND)
    out SPL, r16
    sei    ; enabling interrupts

Start:
    ldi r16, 0b000000
    out DDRB, r16
    in r16, MCUCR       ; change triggering edge for the interrupt
    ori r16, 0x03
    out MCUCR, r16
    ldi r16, 0x60
    out GIMSK, r16      ; PCIE
    out GIFR, r16
    ldi r16, 0x01
    out PCMSK, r16

Loop:
    rjmp  Loop
```

In section after `Start` label all the registers and flags enabling interrupts are set according to the [datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/images/doc2535.pdf) pages 44 through 47. These are `I` in `SREG`, `ISC00` and `ISC01` in `MCUCR`, `PCINT0` in `PCMSK`, `PCIE, INT0` in `GIMSK` and `PCIF` in `GIFR`.

Debugging in Proteus however shows that INT0 (second vector) is being triggered, but not PCINT0 (third vector).

Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

---

**Update**

Several changes to code were suggested in comments and this is how I've altered the code, which is still not cause an interrupt on button press while simulating in Proteus.

```
Reset:
    ldi r16, low(RAMEND)
    out SPL, r16


Start:
    ldi r16, 0b000000
    out DDRB, r16       ; port B input/output
    ldi r16, 0x20
    out GIFR, r16       ; clearing interrupt flag
    out GIMSK, r16      ; Pin change interrupt enable
    ldi r16, 0x01
    out PCMSK, r16      ; enable PCINT0
    sei
```

---

**Update 2**

I'm using Proteus 8 v8.1 *with advanced simulation* on Windows 8 (x64), after that I've updated to Proteus 8.4. Result is still the same.

Comment: Where do you set actually `I` (Global Interrupt Enable) in `SREG`, in your code? You said you set it but I cannot see it in your code.

Comment: @Bence There's a SEI right after SP initialization. - Not that I advocate enabling interrupts before all initialization is done, but it should work.

Comment: @JimmyB - Thanks you are right, I have just missed that spot.

Comment: Writing 0x60 to the GIMSK enables *both* the INT0 and PCINT0...5. Use 0x40 for INT0 or 0x20 for pcint.

Comment: Also, the `ISC0x` bits only apply to INT0, not pin change ones, so are irrelevant.

Comment: As well, if you feel the need to clear the flags by writing to `GIFR` when you enable the interrupts, you should do so before enabling them - i.e. the write to `GIFR` should be before the write to `GIMSK`.

Comment: I wonder if proteus is at fault. The code so far as I can tell should work.

Comment: @TomCarpenter are there any other means of testing the code without uploading code to the chip? (On Windows or Linux).

Comment: I've never used it but I noticed [simavr](https://github.com/buserror/simavr) is available for Linux. It's surprising the number of Proteus questions that get asked here where it turns out Proteus was the problem.

Comment: Your updated code works OK in AVR Studio 4 simulator.